# Are there any ways to change Java Swing GUI icon on Netbeans Swing GUI Builder?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, builder

Are there any ways to let Netbeans Swing GUI Builder do the work of changing the GUI application icon and automate the codes required?
I know eclipse with WindowBuilder Pro plugin will be able to do that for me but I just want to check if this can be done using Swing GUI Builder.

TIA.

Comment: *"Are there any ways to let Netbeans Swing GUI Builder do the work of changing the GUI application icon and automate the codes required?"*  Yes, there are.  I don't know *what* they are since I don't use Netbeans, but there are ways to do it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Especially the part *"automate the codes*" does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

1) not this is not possible, method `Frames.getFrames()` is private method and not accesible from outside, for Container based on Java Desktop Application

2) use [Standard Swing JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), and wrote your code by your hands, then you'll never solve another issues rellated with this depreciated GUI Framework

Comment: Why do you think user1227820 is using the Swing Application Framework?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name by keyword `Netbeans Swing GUI Builder`, AFAIK only in this Framework isn't possible do that directly, required  additional Woodoo

Comment: @mKorble: the `Netbeans Swing GUI Builder` as nothing to do with the Swing Application Framework (although older versions of the GUI builder did support the SAF)

Comment: hmmm SAF???, then for OP will be more that an alternative use palette with SwingX JComponents (again alive, supported),